# Trying to write a code that will open a file with a changing source name and file name based on month

Tags: excel, vba

I am a total beginner at this and I can write the code to open a certain file but the location of the file and file name will change monthly and I am not sure how to adjust the code.

So for example, below, let's say this is where my data source comes from that I want my macro to open the file, where ultimately I will copy and paste.

The file path where will be    \Sales\MONTH END CLOSE\**2020**\**08 Aug**\Reports\Unit A

The file will be called    "Sales Report **2020-08**"

So there are a couple of constants where the path of the data is saved, but there are three variables that are bolded above, the year, the month, and the end of the name of the file.

What I am hoping to do is is create some function inside my excel (where I want the data source to be pasted to) that will be able to change based on the month then the macro will be able to pick up on that and know the path of where the desired file is stored to then properly open it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a function to return the full name of the file. The value returned by the function can then be used as an argument for the `WorkBook.Open` method. Here's the function.

```
Function FullFileName(ByVal Mth As Integer, _
                      Optional ByVal Yr As Integer) As String

    Const Path      As String = "C:\Sales\MONTH END CLOSE\"
    Const SubPath   As String = "\Reports\Unit A\"              ' end on backslash
    
    Dim Dat         As Date
    Dim Fun         As String               ' function return value
    
    If Yr = 0 Then Yr = Year(Date)          ' use current year if omitted
    If Yr < 100 Then Yr = Yr + 2000         ' "20" becomes "2020"
    Dat = DateSerial(Yr, Mth, 1)            ' create a date from year and month
    
    Fun = Path & CStr(Yr) & "\" & Format(Dat, "mm mmm")
    Fun = Fun & SubPath & "Sales Report " & Format(Dat, "yyyy-mm") & ".xlsx"
    
    FullFileName = Fun
End Function
```

Call the function as shown below.

```
Dim Ffn As String
Ffn = FullFileName(8, 20)
' or
Ffn = FullFileName(8, 2020)
' or simply
Ffn = FullFileName(8)
```

You might also embed the function call in the Open method.

```
Dim MyWb As Workbook
Set MyWb = Workbooks.Open(FullFileName(8))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Sub Openfile()

Dim Path1 As Variant
Dim Path2 As Variant
Dim Path3 As Variant
Dim Path4 As Variant
Dim DataDate As Variant

Dim FinalPath As String

DataDate = Sheet1.Range("A1").Value

Path1 = "C:\Sales\MONTH END CLOSE\"
Path2 = Format(DataDate, "YYYY")
Path3 = Format(DataDate, "MM MMM")
Path4 = "\Reports\Unit A\"
Path5 = Format(DataDate, "YYYY-DD")

FinalPath = Path1 & Path2 & "\" & Path3 & Path4 & "Sales Report " & Path5 & ".xlsx"

Workbooks.Open FinalPath

End Sub
```

Paste in a module and call it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I ended up getting a syntax compile error for the final path part of the code

Comment: Hi I edited the Code Kindly try it again. It works to my excel. Just make sure that the date on the Cell A1 is formatted this way MM\DD\YYYY.

Comment: Thanks. I see there was a miscommunication. The file path is below 

 \Sales\MONTH END CLOSE\2020\08 Aug\Reports\Unit A

the "08 Aug" is not saying August 8th, 2020. It is saying 08 as in the month of August and then lists the first three letters of the month. So it's really month, month. need to figure out a way for vba to pick that up

Comment: Just Change the Path3  to Path3 = Format(DataDate, "MM MMM")

Comment: and if your excel file "Sales Report 2020-08.xlsx" where 08 is also a month then change Path5 = Format(DataDate, "YYYY-DD") to Path5 = Format(DataDate, "YYYY-MM").

Comment: I ended up finding a way easier way to do this. Not sure if it's "good code" but I created a function inside excel that would create the name of the file path into a cell. Then just used the following code --- Workbooks.Open Filename:=Cells(1,1).Value --- on that specific cell and it worked.

Comment: Can also be done like that. But its vulnerable to accidental deletion. Hoping you close this thread. And Vote for your own code.